# Same autorization between different web app (and api)

Tags: .net, authorization, asp.net-identity, jwt

This is a conceptual question:

I have a Autorization Server that use Microsoft Identity to generate JWT.

The JWT is uses to access confidential resources in many servers (same authorization identities).

What is the preferred way to implement same authorization by MVC to authorized in defferent web api server, and do it also in defferent NodeJS server consider the following:

1. Step 6 is need to be efficient (Every req need a JWT decoding and validating?)
2. Do all of these six steps need to be realized on the NodeJS erver as well?

[image: Auth flow]

Answer (score 0):

You can do application  trust since you are already using JWT.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831532(v%3Dws.11).

You can use Owin authentication as an example. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application

We usually do this if you have a different application for front end (Angular, React, Node) then another application for the API Layer. With this the API will have an authorization function and wont be accessible unless your Token is valid and it from the Trusted front end application.

Hopes this help.